# Creating a dropdown list in MVC nhibernate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, drop-down-menu

I'm creating an application in hibernate where i need to create a dropdown list in my Create View.

The dropdownlist items are fetched through a function called `getHobbytype()` and from that I need to store the selected value into a different database.

I have written this in my controller:

```
ViewData["Hobby_type"] = 
       new SelectList(new  Hobby_MasterService().GetHobbyType(),"Hobby_Types");
```

And this in my Create View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Model => 
       Model.Hobby_Types,(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Hobby_type"])
```

Through this I'm able to create the dropdown list but it is giving me this error inside my view on the dropdown:

> There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'Hobby_Types'.

Here is my GetHobbyType Method:

```
 public IList<String> GetHobbyType()
 {
   log.Debug("Started");
   ISession session = DataAccessLayerHelper.OpenReaderSession();
    IList<String> htype = null;
   ITransaction transaction = null;
  try
  {
    transaction = session.BeginTransaction();
    htype = session.CreateSQLQuery("SELECT Hobby_Types FROM Hobby_Type").List<String> ();
  session.Flush();
 transaction.Commit();
}
    catch (Exception ex)
 {
   if (transaction != null && transaction.IsActive)
   transaction.Rollback();
   log.Error(ex);

  }
  log.Debug("End");
  return htype;
  }
```

Please tell me where I'm going wrong.

Comment: ViewData["Type"] I suppose you mean ViewData["Hobby_Type"]

Comment: Can you also post the `GetHobbyType` method please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a typo:-

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Model => 
       Model.Hobby_Types,(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Type"])
```

Should it not be

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Model => 
       Model.Hobby_Types,(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Hobby_type"])
```

Also your error says  `'IEnumerable' that has the key 'Hobby_Types'.`

The key in ViewData is case sensitive (not to mention the error has an S on the end)

I would also reccomend using a ViewModel rather than ViewData. See this [Google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=mvc%20dropdown%20ist%20viewmodel#hl=en&sa=X&psj=1&ei=aSFoT4rvI5OzhAfeoYTECg&ved=0CBwQvwUoAQ&q=mvc%20dropdownlist%20viewmodel&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=d55cb96761b0cfac&biw=1454&bih=726) search

**edit** The `GetHobbyType` Method returns a List so try this:-

```
 ViewData["Hobby_type"] =    
   new SelectList(
    new Hobby_MasterService().GetHobbyType()
     .Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x, Value = x }).ToList()
   ,"Hobby_Types");
```

I also suggest looking at using a viewmodel as it will save you lots of headaches!

Comment: yah its Hobby_Type ... but i dont want to create view model....can u tell me any method without it

Comment: Edit posted as you method is returning a List<string>

Answer (score -1):

You can try this all.

You have to write a service `named GetAllStudents()`

```
public IList<Student> GetAllStudents()
{

    log.Debug("Started");
    ISession session = DataAccessLayerHelper.OpenReaderSession();
    IList<Student> students = null;
    ITransaction transaction = null;
    try
    {
        transaction = session.BeginTransaction();

        ICriteria criteria = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Student));
        students = criteria.List<Student>();
        session.Flush();
        transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (transaction != null && transaction.IsActive)
            transaction.Rollback();
        log.Error(ex);

    }
    finally
    {
        if (transaction != null)
            transaction.Dispose();

        if (session != null && session.IsConnected)
            session.Close();
    }

    log.Debug("End");
    return students;
}
```

In controller:

```
ViewBag.std = new StudentService().GetAllStudents(); // ViewBag.std will hold all students.
```

In create View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Name, new SelectList(ViewBag.std, "Id", "Name"), "-- Select --")
```

- First parameter is responsible for Linq expression for class property which you want to place in dropdown.
- Second one is `IEnumerable` item list.
- Third data value field.(Primary key)
- Last one is Data text field which you want to display in drop down list.