# To store selected value from dropdown list in mvc3 nhibernate

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, html.dropdownlistfor

I am using nhibernate and want to create a simple dropdown list
here is senario:
I have a product class consist of name, type of product, and its value along with id
the Type of product is foreign key here which is primary key in my Product_Type class
alli need to do is add the product in tables
and for that i need a dropdownlist to show all type of products

Model for Product

```
  public class Product_Type
{
    public virtual int Prod_Type_Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual string Prod_Types { get; set; }
 }

 public class Product
{
    public virtual int Product_Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual string Product_Name { get;set; }
    public virtual Product_Type Prod_Types { get; set; }
  }
```

I created mapping file where i mapped the Product_Types to table Product as foriegn key

I wrote this in my controller

```
  ViewData["prod_types"] = new SelectList(new Product_Service().GetProdType().ToList(), "Product_Type");
```

where GetProdType is a function populating list
In the view i am populating my list as

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(Model=>Model.Prod_Types,(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["prod_types"]);
```

But it is giving me an error as
    There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'Prod_Types'.

i searched in other forum but did not get a proper answer
Please help me for this
Thank you!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a dropdown list in MVC nhibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9781576/creating-a-dropdown-list-in-mvc-nhibernate)

Answer (score 1):

You used the same key in ViewData as the property you are binding to. Try like this:

```
ViewData["AvailableProductTypes"] = new SelectList(
    new Product_Service().GetProdType().ToList(), 
    "Prod_Type_Id",
    "Prod_Types"
);
```

and in the view:

```
@model Product_Type
...
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.Prod_Type_Id,
    (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["AvailableProductTypes"]
)
```

Comment: By ProdTypeId.... which id are u indicating???
one in Product table on which my view is based or in Product_Type table fromwhich my dropdown is populating..... please specify..

Comment: One in your view model. The one which you want to use later in your POST controller action to read the selected value.

Comment: ....are usuggesting me to create a viewmodel for this???
Because this again gives me an error for databinding as: 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'ProductTypeId'

Comment: I am not using any viewmodel... cant I create this without that

Comment: Ah so the Prod_Types property is of type string? In this case you could keep it as first argument but then use some other key in the ViewData not `prod_types`. As far as the view model is concerned it's not a requirement. You could do it without a view model. It's not a requirement to write proper code.

Comment: I can show you an example but since I recommend the usage of view models my example will contain them. But because you said that you don't want to use view models if you want me to help you, you could show your models so that I can see what you are doing wrong.

Comment: @ Darin Dimitrov: iupdated my question can u please take a look at it and tel me where i am going wrong

Comment: Dimtrov....I thnk i forgot to tell you that my view depends on Product not on Product_Type.....so now wat can i do...??Do ihave to create a viewmodel??

Comment: @MVC_Nhibernate, yes, you should create a view model. But as I already explained it is not required. Don't you have some scalar property on this `Product` class that you could bind the selected value to? If you don't you could use the weakly typed version: `@Html.DropDownList("SelectedProductTypeId", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["AvailableProductTypes"])`